# Select UL in Class

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, pug

I'm trying to select the "ul" in my own class but it's not working.
I'm not sure what i missed out?

Here is the scss

```
body {
.myFooter {
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
  }
}
```

this is my pug file

```
body
        .container.bottomContent
            .row
                .col-lg-12
                    .myFooter
                        ul
                            li
                                a(href="#") test
                            li
                                a(href="#") test3
```

I tried to put the .myFooter outside of the body scss but it's not working either.

Comment: 1. You don't need `body` in your rule.  2.  If this post reflects the pug indentation you are using, you don't have the DOM you think you do.  Check that the HTML is rendering correctly first, then write the rule in dev tools.  If that works, your sass rule will work.

Comment: Can you confirm you're compiling the scss to css and using that?

Comment: @sean yes, rest of it works, jmargolisvt i tried both.

Comment: Please provide the compiled HTML and CSS files.

Comment: just wanted to post the file, but now it's fixed, i didn't do something. anyways thanks for your help